# In ionic how to set storage to login information so when restarting the app takes directly to the home page

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4, ionic-storage

I am using the ionic framework. How do I set storage to login information so if the app restart the user can go to the home page when filling the login information again and again.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {


  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}

    loginUser(value){
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Log In Successful, UID: ' + value.uid + 'Email: ' + 
       value.email);
         this.storage.set('Email', value.email);
         this.storage.set('Password', value.password);
      })
      }
    }
```

Comment: do you have any page before the login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ref. My github Url](https://github.com/manzooralam/PreventPageAccessByAngularGuardsIonic_4)

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ToastController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  authState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private storage: Storage,
    private platform: Platform,
    public toastController: ToastController
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.ifLoggedIn();
    });
  }


  ifLoggedIn() {
    this.storage.get('USER_INFO').then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        this.authState.next(true);
      }
    });
  }


  login() {
    var dummy_response = {
      user_id: 'manzoor.alam@thinktac.com',
      user_name: 'manzoor'
    };
    this.storage.set('USER_INFO', dummy_response).then((response) => {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      this.authState.next(true);
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.storage.remove('USER_INFO').then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      this.authState.next(false);
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authState.value;
  }
}
```

In auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor( public authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

App.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/Authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private router: Router,

    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService

  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      this.authenticationService.authState.subscribe(state => {
        if (state) {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      });

    });

  }
}
```

In app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';


const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  // { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  // { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  // { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule' },

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
    // Here canActivate is a method inside the AuthGuardService which return boolen type values
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Please Ref. My github url more details [github Url](https://github.com/manzooralam/PreventPageAccessByAngularGuardsIonic_4)**

Comment: If that is your github, [you must disclose your affiliation in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Shouldn't that splash screen be hidden after the next screen has been decided inside the auth service callback?

Answer (score 0):

Use Router Guard.

A Guard is just an Angular service - or injectable - that controls the behavior of the router in a maintainable way. Let’s generate it with the CLI:

```
ionic generate guard guards/login
```

The guard contains a special canActivate method that we are required to implement that must return or resolve to a boolean value. Because Ionic Storage is Promise-based, we can just make it an async function. Its job is to read the loginComplete value from the device storage. If true it allows the route to active, but if false it will block the route and redirect to the login.

```
// ...omitted
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {

    const isComplete = await this.storage.get('loginComplete');

    if (!isComplete) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }

    return isComplete;
  }
}
```

**Applying the Guard**

> app-routing.module

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginGuard } from './guards/login.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule',
    canActivate: [LoginGuard] // <-- apply here 
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
  }
];
@NgModule(...)
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Login page**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {


  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}

    loginUser(value){
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Log In Successful, UID: ' + value.uid + 'Email: ' + 
       value.email);
         this.storage.set('Email', value.email);
         this.storage.set('Password', value.password);
           this.storage.set('loginComplete', true);
      })
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Ref url: [AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic4-intro-slides-tutorial-to-educate-app-users/)